# Generalised Taylor theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, taylor-expansion

Given an analytic function $f$ defined on a domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}$, suppose there is a point $w \in D$ such that $f^\prime(w) = 0$. Then it is well known that there is a local conformal change of variables that makes $f$ exactly quadratic. Namely there is a biholomorphism $\zeta:= \zeta(z)$ such that $f(z) = f(w) + \zeta^2$. This is trivial because one simply takes $\zeta = \sqrt{f(z) - f(w)}$ which is holomorphic on a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $w$.

The "generalisation" I am wondering about this. Let $f(z_1,z_2)$ be a holomorphic function in two variables defined on $D_1 \times D_2$ where $D_1, D_2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ are open domains. Suppose there is a $(w_1,w_2) \in D_1 \times D_2$ such that
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1} f(z_1,z_2)\right)_{(z_1,z_2) = (w_1,w_2)} = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_2} f(z_1,z_2)\right)_{(z_1,z_2) = (w_1,w_2)} = 0$$
Then do there exist holomorphic functions $\zeta_1 = \zeta_1(z_1,z_2)$, $\zeta_1 = \zeta_2(z_1,z_2)$ (with non-vanishing Jacobian) such that
$$f(z_1,z_2) = f(w_1,w_2) + \zeta_1^2 + \zeta_2^2$$
I feel like this is an algebraic geometry question but I'm not sure.

Comment: this is a local problem so it comes down to diagonalizing the Hessian which is of course a symmetric matrix so it's doable; note though that you need it to be nonsingular as in the one dimensional case - your result doesn't hold if $f''(w)=0$ so you need the condition $f''(w) \ne 0$ in the one dimensional case and the analogue in two or more dimensions

Comment: @Conrad Is diagonalising the Hessian enough? We have a full Taylor series and the Hessian only relates to the second order term. Also, the diagonalisation of the Hessian is something done pointwise -- it's not obvious to me there is a system of coordinates that diagonalises the Hessian on an open set.

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of the Hessian are locally analytic (and non zero) around $(w_1,w_2)$ by the implicit function theorem, I think it should follow that diagonalization is possible locally by an analytic change of variables; anyway look up Weierstrass preparation theorem to give you more insight; the general result indeed may not be true since the shape of the zero set given by $\zeta_1^2 + \zeta_2^2=0$ is very specific, but there are normal local forms in several variables too, just may be more complicated than the one you want